# Redux State state works only on the first Load

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm going through a weird error with Redux (@toolkit) and its state when it is iterated, so the problem as i could track is this, when a specific page is loaded, in my case "Order page" it calls the function to load the orders, then puts on the state, and then the loader is off and iterates through the data, and it works just fine, but the problem it happenes when I visit other pages and come back to the same page with the loaded state, I get this specific error, as it can't iterate through the data even is loaded, and I don't understand why.

The error: `Uncaught TypeError: orders.orders.map is not a function at Orders`

This is how I load data with UseEffect when user is loaded so I can use the token.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllOrders(user.token));
  }, [user]);
```

And here is my function with createAsyncThunk with Redux Slices:

```
export const fetchOrder = createAsyncThunk('', async ({token, id}) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}/orders/view/${id}`, requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

And here is the state:

```
export const orderSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'order',
  initialState: {
    order: null,
    message: null,
    isLoading: true,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchOrder.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.message = 'Fetching the Order...';
    },

    [fetchOrder.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.message = 'Something went wrong fetching the Order.';
    },

    [fetchOrder.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.order = action.payload.data;
      state.message = 'Succesfully fetched the Order.';
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Maybe is because the state is loaded, and something that we can't find is happening?

Comment: Yes, i mentioned the same, I think this is the case, let's hope for peope to share their thoughts and fixes.

Comment: Try to debug the state. Print the state in your component to check what it is